# How to Load lables via Properties file in FreeMarker

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker, label

I am using Spring MVC + FreeMarker integration. As I am new to FreeMarker i am not able to find out a way to configure FreeMarker labels from properties file.

Kindly help me out on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, 'ResourceBundleMessageSource', message source for this.

```
<bean id="messageSource"   
           class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
      <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/messages" />
      <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
/>
```

Define the locale resolver,

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>
```

Define localeChangeInterceptor which detects the language parameter from the user session and call locale resolve. And register the interceptor in handler Mappings.

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>
```

```
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
        <property name="interceptors">
           <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
           </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Property files  need to be defined like,

- messages_en.properties
- messages_ar.properties

inside the messages folder path.

'ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource' can be used if the language property files frequently changes. That means you don't have to restart the application in each language file change.

You need to import spring macro,

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>
```

and

messages can be accessed inside a .ftl as follows.

```
<@spring.message "customMessageKey"/>
```

Comment: How it decides messages_en.properties or messages_ar.properties will be used?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Interceptor provides the language parameter which is used in localeResolver.