# Use property file in freemarker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I have a properties file like for example *.properties
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

i want to use this key value in my freemarker template. Like for example
<#assign variable1 = key1 variable2 = value1 >
Is there way to do this

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26576011/3635454

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you create the data-model (the context, the variables) in Java, and then call the tempalte. So in this case, you can load the `.properties` file into a `java.util.Properties` object, then use that as the data-model (i.e., you pass it to `Template.process(dataModel)`), or add it to a bigger data-model under some variable name. That all happens in Java.

There's no build in capability to load things directly from the template. If you need to do that, then you have to expose such functionality either through the data-model (the public methods of the exposed objects can be called from the template), or by writing a library (FTL file that pulls in your `TemplateModel` implementations via `?new`) for it.